# Not able to bind key property with Alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

The following code does not work as expected.

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body x-data="{name: 'test', value: 1}">
    <button :key="name" @click="alert(Alpine.bound($el, 'key', 'unknown'))">
        click
    </button>
    </template>
</body>
```

After clicking the button, it should display "test", while it display "unknown" instead. What's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Alpine.js `:key` works with x-for. It might be a bug. `:key` becomes a reserved property. You could check the implementation of x-bind.

```js
directive('bind', (el, { value, modifiers, expression, original }, { effect }) => {
    ...

    if (value === 'key') return storeKeyForXFor(el, expression)

    let evaluate = evaluateLater(el, expression)

    effect(() => evaluate(result => {
        // If nested object key is undefined, set the default value to empty string.
        if (result === undefined && typeof expression === 'string' && expression.match(/\./)) {
            result = ''
        }

        mutateDom(() => bind(el, value, result, modifiers))
    }))
})
```

So just avoid use `:key`, choose another name.

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body x-data="{name: 'test', value: 1}">
    <button :alter-key="name" @click="alert(Alpine.bound($el, 'alter-key', 'unknown'))">
        click
    </button>
    </template>
</body>
```